# Setting up an email account using godaddy's cpanel hosting service

Tags: email, cpanel, godaddy

I just recently purchased a cpanel hosting service with GoDaddy. Next I set up hosting for a domain which was registered on a different GoDaddy account. For this I edited the DNS record in the second account (the one which registered the domain) to point to the ip of my cpanel server. This worked just fine.

The problem is when I set up an email (using cpanel), I can't send or receive emails to/from the domain. Not sure how to set up the MX records but tried by setting the MX record to point to mail.mydomain.com and created an A record to point mail.mydomain.com to the ip of the cpanel server. This isn't working, not sure how to proceed from here and would appreciate any help.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mistaking A records with MX records, `mail.example.com` is an A record setup automatically by cPanel and is not relevant to the setup of MX records which are needed for email to work.

The easiest solution would be to [find out the name servers](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/find-your-websites-nameservers-in-cpanel-hosting-16140) that your hosting uses and then change the domain name servers to that of the hosting, then the records are automatically set up for you.

If you would rather do it manually then you need to [check which MX records](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/checking-and-managing-my-mx-records-7590) you should be using, for example:

- `smtp.sercureserver.net` priority 0
- `mailstore1.secureserver.net` priority 10

Changing the domain records or name servers can take between 1-72 hours to take effect, even with new domains.

Then in your email client, you can use `mail.example.com` for the POP3/IMAP/SMTP settings, however its advisable to [login to their email server using their own domains](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/mail-server-addresses-and-ports-for-setting-up-your-email-24071) for SSL purposes and speed.